# how replace the comment in the following code with a while loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

how replace the comment in the following code with a while loop in python.

Comment: concatenate X to toPrint numXs times

```html
numXs = int(input('How many times should I print the letter X? '))
toPrint = ''
if numXs == 1:
    toPrint = 'X'
elif numXs == 2:
    toPrint = 'XX'
elif numXs == 3:
    toPrint = 'XXX'
print(toPrint)
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Show some attempt, even a bad one. Then ask what is not clear or what you struggle with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decrement `numXs` for each iteration until it is no longer greater than 0:

```
numXs = int(input('How many times should I print the letter X? '))
toPrint = ''
while numXs > 0:
    toPrint += 'X'
    numXs -= 1
print(toPrint)
```